# Ubuntu Linux 18.04 WSL in Windows: MariaDB service start fails

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mariadb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After installing MariaDB repository configuration tool for the first time in my Linux WSL for Windows (as described in [MariaDB Download Page](https://mariadb.org/download/)), I executed `mysql` but there was a socket error. `netstat -apn | grep mysql` shows nothing, indicating the mysql service is stopped; `sudo apt list | grep *mysql-server*` shows I had successfully installed `mysql-server`.

However, as I tried `sudo service mysql start`, the command line gives:

```sh
 * Starting MariaDB database server mysqld                 [fail]
```

I tried the following methods, but all failed and yielded the same answer:

- Using `/etc/init.d/mysql start`
- Removing `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0` and `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1`
- Upgrading access of `/var/lib/mysql` using `chmod -R 777 /var/lib/mysql`
- Removing everything from `/var/lib/mysql/`
- Changing port setting using `port=1112` in `/etc/my.cnf` (since I have another mysql on the Windows side)
- Filling in additional information in `/etc/my.cnf` (my configuration file was initially empty after installation, and I filled in the `basedir`, `datadir`, `socket`, `log_error`, and `pid-file` properties)
- Trying `systemctl` instead of `service` (this failed because Linux WSL uses `sysvinit` instead of `systemd`)

How could I start my MariaDB service? Thanks

Comment: What about sudo service mysql status?

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how you installed MariaDB?  There are lots of different methods detailed on the page you linked to.  Which options did you select on that page?  The default that comes up if you are on Windows is for the *Windows* version (not a Linux version under WSL).  Also, what distribution are you using under WSL?  Ubuntu?  Something else?

Comment: @RamanSailopal ```sudo service mysql status``` yields ``` * MariaDB is stopped. ```

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I downloaded the **Repository Configuration Tool** as described [here](https://mariadb.org/download/), {Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, MariaDB Server version: 10.5, Mirror: Vietnam Hanoi}. The actual commands I used are ```sudo apt-get install software-properties-common dirmngr apt-transport-https```, ```sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys 'https://mariadb.org/mariadb_release_signing_key.asc'```, ```sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,arm64,ppc64el] https://mirrors.bkns.vn/mariadb/repo/10.5/ubuntu bionic main'```, ```sudo apt update```, ```sudo apt install mariadb-server```.

Comment: The install steps look reasonable.  I'm not sure where MariaDB puts its logs by default (and it probably depends on your distribution, which looks to be Ubuntu based on the installation steps).  It's probably in either `/var/log/mysql` or `/var/lib/mysql`.  Is there any information in there that could be of use?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Seems like ```/var/log/mysql/error.log``` contains error logs for a whole, not for each mysql start trial. The only error in this log is ```2021-01-12 14:15:32 7fc9b3520c80 InnoDB: Error: Linux Native AIO interface is not supported on this platform. Please check your OS documentation and install appropriate binary of InnoDB.
InnoDB: You can disable Linux Native AIO by setting innodb_use_native_aio = 0 in my.cnf```, but ```service mysql start``` still failed after adding ```innodb_use_native_aio=0``` in ```/etc/my.cnf```.

Comment: Furthermore: in ```/var/lib/mysql```, ```ib_logfile0``` and ```aria_log_control``` contains non-readable characters, and ```ib_logfile1``` & ```aria_log.00000001``` are empty.

Comment: So I spun up a cloned instance to try this myself.  I was able to get it running no problem under Ubuntu 20.04 with WSL2.  However, when I convert that same instance to WSL1, it fails.  Among other things that sound similar to your problem, `/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf` is not created during the MariaDB installation under WSL1, leading to the "empty" `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` which is a symlink to `/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf`.  Can you confirm whether you are running WSL1 or WSL2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce your problem (or one that looks an awfully lot like it) on WSL1.  Can you confirm that you are using WSL1?

I spun up two cloned instances (`wsl --import` of a clean backup) of Ubuntu 20.04 -- One on WSL1 and the other on WSL2.  Unfortunately, I don't have a handy 18.04 to work with, but I'm hoping the problem is the same.

On WSL2, everything worked properly.  After the installation steps (pretty much the ones you put in your comment, but for 20.04), I was able to:

`sudo service mariadb start`

and then `sudo mysql -u root` successfully.

On WSL1, however, the MariaDB installation seems to fail in a strange way.  It does not create `/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf`, which leads to what you saw with an empty `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, since it's a symlink to `mariadb.cnf`.

So I created mariadb.cnf manually:

`sudo vi /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf`

with the contents:

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 0. "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" symlinks to this file, reason why all the rest is read.
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# If you are new to MariaDB, check out https://mariadb.com/kb/en/basic-mariadb-articles/

#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
# port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

This is simply the default `mariadb.cnf` that was created correctly by the installation on WSL2.

Attempting to start the service then gave an error about a missing `/etc/mysql/debian-start`, so I repeated the same steps of copying it over:

`sudo vi /etc/mysql/debian-start`

With the contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This script is executed by "/etc/init.d/mariadb" on every (re)start.
#
# Changes to this file will be preserved when updating the Debian package.
#
# NOTE: This file is read only by the traditional SysV init script, not systemd.
#

source /usr/share/mysql/debian-start.inc.sh

# Read default/mysql first and then default/mariadb just like the init.d file does
if [ -f /etc/default/mysql ]; then
  . /etc/default/mysql
fi

if [ -f /etc/default/mariadb ]; then
  . /etc/default/mariadb
fi

MYSQL="/usr/bin/mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf"
MYADMIN="/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf"
# Don't run full mysql_upgrade on every server restart, use --version-check to do it only once
MYUPGRADE="/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade --defaults-extra-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf --version-check"
MYCHECK="/usr/bin/mysqlcheck --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf"
MYCHECK_SUBJECT="WARNING: mysqlcheck has found corrupt tables"
MYCHECK_PARAMS="--all-databases --fast --silent"
MYCHECK_RCPT="${MYCHECK_RCPT:-root}"

## Checking for corrupt, not cleanly closed (only for MyISAM and Aria engines) and upgrade needing tables.

# The following commands should be run when the server is up but in background
# where they do not block the server start and in one shell instance so that
# they run sequentially. They are supposed not to echo anything to stdout.
# If you want to disable the check for crashed tables comment
# "check_for_crashed_tables" out.
# (There may be no output to stdout inside the background process!)

# Need to ignore SIGHUP, as otherwise a SIGHUP can sometimes abort the upgrade
# process in the middle.
trap "" SIGHUP
(
  upgrade_system_tables_if_necessary;
  check_root_accounts;
  check_for_crashed_tables;
) >&2 &

exit 0
```

And then `chmod 755 /etc/mysql/debian-start`

After that, voila:

`sudo service mariadb restart`

`sudo mysql -u root`

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 32
Server version: 10.5.8-MariaDB-1:10.5.8+maria~focal mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Given the steps you've tried so far, I'd recommend blowing away pretty much all of it to try to start over "clean":

```
sudo apt remove mariadb-server
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/mysql
```

Then reinstall mariadb-server and follow the steps above to create the correct files.

Comment: Thanks! I am using a WSL2 18.04 LTS. I tried to add the socket=xxx line in my ```/etc/mysql/my.cnf``` (which was generated along with ```mariadb.cnf```) but it still failed. The ```/etc/mysql/debian-start``` is also present. I am currently trying to remove everything as you suggested and reinstall mariadb-server. Thank you :D

Comment: After removing everything, make sure to do a `wsl --terminate <distroname>` to simulate a "shutdown", just to make sure nothing's hanging around in memory.

Comment: Also check out [this WSL issue report](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3631#issuecomment-720772732) and the comments.  The one I linked to directly mentions a possible solution for the AIO error.  And [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3631#issuecomment-584140246) has a solid plan for removing.